OpenBSD's signify doesn't work on macOS (signify-osx) Sonoma - Could not verify signature
I wish to verifiy a GrapheneOS release I downloaded. This OpenBSD's signify looks like more secure sha512sum. I did not fully understand it.
This is what I did:
$ brew install signify-osx

$ ssh-keygen -Y verify -f allowed_signers.sig -I contact@grapheneos.org -n "factory images" -s tangorpro-factory-2024071200.zip.sig < /Users/me/Downloads/tangorpro-factory-2024071200.zip

Could not verify signature.

$ ls -lrt
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  144 Jul 17 10:13 allowed_signers.sig
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff  310 Jul 17 10:15 tangorpro-factory-2024071200.zip.sig

$ cat allowed_signers.sig 

untrusted comment: verify with factory.pub
RWQZW9NItOuQYMZY8ZMX9VX4hfy54df7Pt3Yh1qEWTyRlQKH4PdteqeKUk9jljywlcCl8nzKJAj75F70Y5FTsAK4cw2aV+CZcAA=

$ cat tangorpro-factory-2024071200.zip.sig 

-----BEGIN SSH SIGNATURE-----
U1NIU0lHAAAAAQAAADMAAAALc3NoLWVkMjU1MTkAAAAghSD+bkKg/zdvSt9ILNhJUDhzDi
Kvj2KjkY+jFuDF0kQAAAAOZmFjdG9yeSBpbWFnZXMAAAAAAAAABnNoYTUxMgAAAFMAAAAL
c3NoLWVkMjU1MTkAAABApKkue2E4mce5NMqalNZq4ERyZcte1rECYxy7KK9BqwwTX1y4gH
Yc0wwNOd9mTwGAMimJWWw2+23biUFWW5kpBg==
-----END SSH SIGNATURE-----

The error Could not verify signature and signify is not yet documented in internet.
